# SQL Query Fail [Password Change]

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords

I'm working on my website, and I'm trying to create a settings page that allows them to change their password, however every time i try to change my password it displays `Query failed`, if you can spot the problem, it'd be a great help;

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once('auth.php');


$errmsg_arr = array();


$errflag = false;


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}


$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$retpassword = clean($_POST['retpassword']);


if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($retpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Please retype your password';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $retpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'New passwords do not match!';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the settings page
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: settings.php");
    exit();
}


$qry = "UPDATE members SET passwd = ".md5($_POST['password'])." WHERE member_id =  ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);


if($result) {
    header("location: changed.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark since i do not know the error message , instead of :

```
$qry = "UPDATE members SET passwd = ".md5($_POST['password'])." WHERE member_id =  ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."";
```

use this (you forgot to enclose the password in single quotes):

```
$qry = "UPDATE members SET passwd = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' WHERE member_id =  ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."";
```

Comment: thank you very much, sorry I didn't know how to echo the mysql error, this worked. =]

Comment: np, to catch the error use something like this `$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`